# iOS notification in foreground

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, push-notification, notifications

I want to display an image in my iOS notifications.
It's work when the app is on background but not when the app is in foreground.

I'm using react-native-firebase.

Someone could help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you complete the setup in your `AppDelegate.m` file?

Comment: Yes i have follewed the react-native-push-notification-ios doc.  https://github.com/react-native-push-notification-ios/push-notification-ios